# How to reliably detect TypeScript SyntaxKind in TSLint?

Tags: typescript, enums, tslint

I'm writing some custom TSLint rules and discovered I can't rely on `(ASTObject).kind` between TypeScript versions.

For example, in TypeScript `3.4.5`, `enum ts.SyntaxKind` `ImportDeclaration = 249` and `ImportClause = 250`.

However in TypeScript `3.5.3`, `enum ts.SyntaxKind` `ImportDeclaration = 250` and `ImportClause = 251`.

This broke my lint rules. Is there a better way to detect this, or a configuration issue that's not using the enum from the target project and/or causing them to be misaligned?

I couldn't find documentation or other discussions about that so I'm not sure if it went unnoticed (unlikely) or I'm not using it properly.

```
export class Rule extends Rules.AbstractRule {
  public apply(sourceFile: ts.SourceFile): RuleFailure[] {

    for (const statement of sourceFile.statements) {

      // statement.kind / ts.SyntaxKind.ImportDeclaration
      // is 249 in TypeScript 3.4.5, 250 in TypeScript 3.5.3,
      // object property changes for target code, enum stays the same as lint source
      if (statement && statement.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.ImportDeclaration) {
        const importDeclaration: ts.ImportDeclaration = statement as ts.ImportDeclaration;

        // importDeclaration.moduleSpecifier.kind / ts.SyntaxKind.StringLiteral
        // 10 in TypeScript 3.4.5, 10 in TypeScript 3.5.3
        if (importDeclaration.moduleSpecifier && importDeclaration.moduleSpecifier.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.StringLiteral) {
          const moduleSpecifierStringLiteral: ts.StringLiteral = importDeclaration.moduleSpecifier as ts.StringLiteral;
        ...
        }

        // importDeclaration.importClause.kind / ts.SyntaxKind.ImportClause
        // is 250 in TypeScript 3.4.5, 251 in TypeScript 3.5.3
        // object property changes for target code, enum stays the same as lint source
        if (importDeclaration.importClause) {
          if (importDeclaration.importClause.namedBindings) {
            const namedBindings: ts.NamespaceImport | ts.NamedImports = importDeclaration.importClause.namedBindings;
            // namedBindings.kind / ts.SyntaxKind.NamedImports
            // is 252 in TypeScript 3.4.5, 253 in TypeScript 3.5.3
            // object property changes for target code, enum stays the same as lint source
            if (namedBindings && namedBindings.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.NamedImports) {
              const namedImports: ts.NamedImports = namedBindings as ts.NamedImports;
              for (const element of namedImports.elements) {
                const importName: string = element.name.text;
              ...
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say a good try is to switch to the "is-methods" of typescript like:

```
if (!ts.isImportDeclaration(statement)) {
    return;
}
```

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: I went from comparing .kind directly to using the methods but it seems like they also fail between versions.  This seems like a super weird problem they would’ve accounted for and I just haven’t found the right way to do it. I might resort to crawling objects and processing the prosperities on a per-occurrence basis.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue that in my npm package I was trying to get import declaration with `ts.isImportDeclaration(node)` which was returning false for every node even though there clearly were import declarations in my file.

Eventually it turned out that the problem is that I have a typescript dependency in my npm package which is different version from what the application I'm using the package in has. So the solution was to change the npm package so that the typescript is dev and peer dependency, not standard dependency.